# How Can I open a file using clicking while a java program is continuously writing to it

Tags: java, file

I have a java program which is running continuously and writing to a text file when some data is available at an URL.
I want to view the file periodically going to the directory manually.
But while I try to click the file I get the following message:
[image]

I don't want to see this message and want to see the file contents.
I am wondering is it possible?
What change is needed in my java code.
This is the while loop which I am running forever to write the the file

```
while (true) {
    int innerday = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    if (innerday != day)
        break;
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(readUrl("url"));
        System.out.print(json.length());
        if (json.length() == 3) {
            String type = (String) json.get("type");
            System.out.println(type);
            JSONObject crs = json.getJSONObject("crs");
            System.out.println(crs.toString());
            JSONArray features = (JSONArray) json.get("features");
            for (Object object: features) {
                writer.write(object.toString());
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        continue;
    }
    Thread.sleep(180000);
}
```

Can anyone suggest me with any solution or idea?

Comment: How about opening it an editor which does not require write-lock on the file while opening? As I dont think you are doing anything wrong here.

Comment: Yes, it seems more like a shortfall of your editor than your code. The editor should at least let you view the file, but not change it, while another process has it open for writing...

Comment: Exactly.. Use something like notepad++ or ultraedit for that purpose

Comment: Thanks. I got it. Changing the editor worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to open the file with the current editor you are using, you need to close the file after you write to it. I'm assuming you are using PrintWriter for this. After your changes, your loop should look like:

```
while(true)
{
    int innerday=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    if(innerday!=day)
        break;
try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(readUrl("url"));
    System.out.print(json.length());
    if(json.length()==3)
    {
        String type=(String) json.get("type");
        System.out.println(type);
        JSONObject crs=json.getJSONObject("crs");
        System.out.println(crs.toString());
        JSONArray features= (JSONArray) json.get("features");
        writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(new File("filename"), true));
        for (Object object : features) {
            writer.write(object.toString());
        }
        writer.close();
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    continue;
}
Thread.sleep(180000);
}
```

Kind of ugly, but it should work.

Also, WordPad may not update automatically as the file grows. For that I recommend [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) or a similar editor.

Comment: This will override the contents of the file in each loop whenever the file is reopened.

Comment: I had forgotten how PrintWriter works. This should work now and it shouldn't overwrite on reopening due to the FileWriter append being set to true.